# Proper casing in citation/bibliography titles using biblatex/Biber

Tags: biblatex, capitalization

My understanding is that bibtex lets the citation style handle capitalization of titles, which is what I would expect from an automated citation tool. Do biblatex and Biber also do this? The document I am working on with these tools seems to be preserving the capitalization in the bib database, which is NOT what I want, and I haven't found any clear references that explain what the expected behavior is.

Comment: How are you calling **biblatex**?

Comment: This is really frustrating. I have hundrets of bib entries and I want title case. It seems like Biblatex only supports either "no styling" (which means inconsistent styling or hours of manual work) or sentence case. Sentence case also converts conference names and everything into sentence case, which I don't want (would need hours of manual escaping)...

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It might depend on the style and language(s) you are using, but generally titles are printed in the field format `titlecase`. By default, `titlecase` has no effect on casing; from `biblatex.def`:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{titlecase}{#1}
```

If you want all titles in sentence case (i.e. first letter capitalized, the rest in lowercase) you can redefine this format:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{titlecase}{\MakeSentenceCase*{#1}}
```

The `\MakeSentenceCase*` command converts its argument to sentence case, except for text enclosed in braces (`{}`). It also generally has no effect on control sequences. However Latin characters in math (`$...$` or `\(...\)`) are affected and [control sequences in `$...$` generate parsing errors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22980/sentence-case-for-titles-in-biblatex/22981#comment-45230). To avoid these issues all math can be wrapped in braces. Wrapping a single character in braces affects its kerning, so the `biblatex` manual recommends wrapping braces around entire words. For example:

```
title = {An Introduction to {LaTeX}}
```

instead of:

```
title = {An Introduction to {L}a{T}e{X}}
```

You can make casing depend on the entry type(s) by adding an optional argument - for example:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{titlecase}{\MakeSentenceCase*{#1}}
```

One catch here is that the `titlecase` format is rolled out to all titles within an entry type. So in the above example both the `title` and `journaltitle` fields would be printed in sentence case. [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22980) addresses how to make title case depend on both the entry and field types.

`\DeclareCaseLangs` specifies all the languages that the starred version `\MakeSentenceCase*` converts to sentence case. By default we have:

```
\DeclareCaseLangs{%     
  american,british,canadian,english,australian,newzealand,USenglish,UKenglish}
```

For further details, see `biblatex` documentation on the above commands and release notes under the heading "Sentence case vs. title case".

> *edit* by @moewe: The `biblatex` documentation recommends the starred version `\MakeSentenceCase*` over the unstarred `\MakeSentenceCase`.
>
> The starred version `\MakeSentenceCase*` only applies sentence casing of the language of the entry (as given in the `langid` field or if it is empty, the surrounding language) is in the list of languages where sentence casing makes sense (as defined by `\DeclareCaseLangs`).
>
> `\MakeSentenceCase` applies sentence casing regardless of the language settings and may result in unwanted capitalisation changes in non-English contexts (German for example has no notion of Title Case vs sentence case and English sentence casing as implemented in `\MakeSentenceCase` would lead violate the rules of orthography).

Comment: Ah, so biblatex automates sentence casing as an override of what is otherwise assumed to be title casing. Clever. Thanks.

Comment: @Jonathan That's right. I assume the underlying reasoning is that a decent macro to convert a string to title case would be quite tedious to construct.

Comment: @Audrey I'm seeing the same thing that Jonathan was seeing ("...document I am working on with these tools seems to be preserving the capitalization in the bib database, which is NOT what I want..."), and I'm sorry to say that I don't quite understand your answer as well as he seems to. I'm finding that whatever text I enter in the title field is typeset exactly as entered in the .bib database (even first character) which seems to differ from what you're saying with sentence case and titlecase above. Shouldn't biblatex (called with \printbibliography) just typeset the bibliography correctly?

Comment: @TeXnewbie The default `titlecase` format doesn't change casing. If you want all titles in sentence case, just add `\DeclareFieldFormat{titlecase}{\MakeSentenceCase{#1}}` to your preamble.

Comment: Thanks @Audrey that helped me understand your answer better. So there is the default (do nothing to change case), and there is SentenceCase (Only first letter of first word of title capitalized), but what about title case capitalization (Each Word of Title Capitalized Except for Words Like 'of' 'and' 'for' et. al.)? I looked at documentation and release notes for `biblatex` as you suggested ("Sentence case vs. title case"), but I see nothing describing how to get `biblatex` to typeset a title (eg. for a book) using Title Case. Am I missing something? Is that determined by the `documentclass`?

Comment: @TeXnewbie That is referred to as "title case". biblatex doesn't offer a title case macro. If you use title case, you can apply it throughout your bib file and use `\MakeSentenceCase` whenever needed. Macros to apply title case [are available](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7992/command-to-uppercase-the-first-letter-of-each-word-in-a-sentence), though biber's sourcemap feature might be better for this job.

Comment: You'd expect that ``\DeclareFieldFormat{titlecase}{\MakeSentenceCase{#1}}`` could be replaced by ``\DeclareFieldFormat{titlecase}{\MakeTitleCase{#1}}`` to get a title case style, but no. But ``\DeclareFieldFormat{apacase}{#1}`` does the trick. Reasons unknown.

Comment: @PatrickT `biblatex` only has a macro to convert text to sentence case. There is no command to convert anything to Title Case. The implicit assumption is that people store titles in Title Case and that a style can convert titles to sentence case if need be. (BibTeX works similarly.) Hence there is no `\MakeTitleCase` and `\DeclareFieldFormat{titlecase}{#1}` simply disables sentence casing. `apacase` instead of `titlecase` is a design decision of `biblatex-apa`. All standard styles use `titlecase`, but `biblatex-apa` has more complex rules and uses `apacase`.

Comment: So if I have hundreds o bib entries that are not capitalized consistently, the only way to get consistent capitalization is using sentence case? But this also applies sentence case to conference names, eg, `Ieee conference on xy` instead of `IEEE Conference on XY`, which looks aweful... Is there no good solution here?

Answer (score 8):

If you are using `biblatex` with `style=apa` and want to keep the casing of your `bib`-file you need to use

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{apacase}{#1}
```

The default is to capitalize only the first letter.

Comment: what file does this go in? Please assist

Comment: Your tex file, directly after initializing biblatex.

Comment: thanks a lot, BenjaminH