# Inserting citation to a http link in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, biblatex, citing

I am a little confused, as to what is best way to cite a reference in the internet?

I was trying to find if I could find any additional information about the reference.

Here is the reference, I intend to put:

```
URL : http://www.ross.net/crc/download/crc_v3.txt 
Author : Ross Williams 
Title : A PAINLESS GUIDE TO CRC ERROR DETECTION ALGORITHMS
```

Comment: It is important to provide a minimal examples. The correct entry type/key depends on the bibliography style.

Comment: I am sorry for not providing one. I am using biblatex package. It was more of a query, what additional information that I need to enter while entering a URL entry. If I am giving a reference to a conf.paper or a book, I would enter author, ISBN, publisher etc..

Comment: I added the tag `biblatex`. Now it is more clear.

Comment: Additional Info: I guess Author, Title and URL are ok. At my university it’s recommended to add the date, when the URL was last checked (in biblatex via `urldate`; I added this to my answer).

Comment: In the above method, how do you link if the link has $ or % sign. Often the % is used as a separator in the links and LaTeX doesn't recognize the link and half of it is commented out. Kindly help!

Answer (score 8):

I’d use `@ONLINE` or `@MISC`. If you’re using `biblatex` every entry type can handle an URL and `urldate` (if given as YYYY-MM-DD even with auto formatting).

**Example**

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ONLINE {key,
    url= {http://www.ross.net/crc/download/crc_v3.txt},
    urldate = {2011-10-02},
    author = {Ross Williams},
    title = {A PAINLESS GUIDE TO CRC ERROR DETECTION ALGORITHMS}
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[english]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

PS: Are sure that you like the title in all capital letters? ;-)

Comment: The correct way is to use `DeclareFieldFormat{title}` to set capital letters.

Comment: Well, it was mentioned in the internet this way. I would not prefer in all capital letters though

Comment: @Kiran: So you just copied the title in capital letters? I’d type all titles with normal lower/uppercase letters and if desired one can change it as Marco mentioned.

Comment: Thanks, I had this understanding that I cannot change the title of the reference and even the case of the characters. Its clear now.. :)

Comment: @KiranChandrashekhar The `title` format is generally used to set titles in quotes or italics. Changes to casing can be made via the format `titlecase`. More details can be found in [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20335).