# How to get BibLaTeX-chicago use title case capitalization?

Tags: biblatex, capitalization, chicago-style

According to the 16th version of the Chicago Manual of Style, titles in the reference list are now supposed to be capitalized in title case style rather than sentence casing. Yet, as far as I understand, BibLaTeX-chicago (0.9.9b) does not seem to make any automatic changes to the capitalization of `.bib`-entries.

Is there any way (except for doing it manually for each entry, of course) to get BibLaTeX-chicago use title case capitalization for the entry field `title` in all entry-types (regardless of how the title is formatted in the `.bib`-field) ?

Here's a MEW:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[authordate,strict,backend=biber, cmsdate=old]{biblatex-chicago}
\begin{filecontents}{bibsample2.bib}
@BOOK{Smith2003,
 title = {This is the book title},
 publisher = {Penguin},
 year = {2003},
 author = {Smith, James},
 address = {London},
    }
@ARTICLE{Doe1970,
 author = {Doe, John J.},
 title = {this is the article title},
 journal = {Great Journal},
 year = {1970},
 volume = {40},
 pages = {207-234},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{bibsample2.bib}
\begin{document}
\autocite{Smith2003}
\autocite{Doe1970}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

So, what I'm looking for is for these titles to be spelled as

This is the Book Title

This is the Article Title

in the output.

I'm using the latest version of BibLaTeX (2.5), Biber (1.5) and BibLaTeX-chicago (0.9.9b).

Any pointers are greatly appreciated..

Comment: I think David Fussner is referring to the fact the CMS no longer calls for sentence-style capitalization in their author-date system. This makes it consistent with their notes system. So biblatex-chicago users don't have to worry about protecting letters/words from automatic down-casing.

Comment: So, you mean that biblatex-chicago is not automatically up-casing anything, but simply refraining from down-casing the titles?

Comment: I think so, yes. That is also the default behaviour in the standard biblatex styles.

Comment: Thanks, that would explain things! Is there any way to add title case capitalization to the bibliography (except by changing each entry's casing by hand..)?

Comment: There are two possible ways - through a formatting directive or using biber's source map. AFAIK neither has been addressed on this site. So you could edit your question to ask for a solution. If you only want some titles headline-style, be sure to specify which ones by field (e.g. `title`, `maintitle`, `journaltitle`) and type (e.g. `@article`, `@book`).

Comment: Although there is doubtlessly a way to force the formatting directives, long-term and for compatibility purposes across different styles and languages, it will be better to fix your `.bib` file: capitalization rules are different depending on the language (e.g., imagine a collection of essays written in different languages: essay titles in, say, English, French, and Italian, but the booktitle in German!).  Now that there is no forced down-casing, `title = {<Whatever>},` can be entered as it should without be according to that language's conventions.

Comment: @jon, the problem I see with "fixing" the `.bib` is that it might contain the original author-intended capitalisation.  Wiping that out / standardising it removes information that might be useful in the future.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Any automatic solution will have a hard time beating a human well-versed in the *Chicago Manual of Style*'s headline-style capitalization rules. So you're probably better off formatting titles in your source file manually. Whenever the document language or bibliography format calls for sentence-style capitalization, it is relatively easy to apply with biblatex's [`\MakeSentenceCase`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20335/4483) macro.

That said you could write a new macro, say `\MakeHeadlineCase`, and apply it in the title formatting directives. Another approach is to use biber's `sourcemap` option. It supports regular expressions and modifies fields before biblatex even sees them, which means the solution is entirely style-independent.

A rough approximation to headline-style capitalization is implemented in the following source mapping. It uses the XML syntax of the biber configuration file `biber.conf`. You can also specify source mappings in the document preamble with biblatex's `\DeclareSourcemap` command.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
<sourcemap>
  <maps datatype="bibtex" map_overwrite="1">
  <map>
    <map_step map_field_source="TITLE"
              map_match="(^|\s)(\w+\S*w*)" map_replace="$1\u\L$2"/>
    <map_step map_field_source="TITLE"
              map_match="\-(\w+)" map_replace="\-\u\L$1"/>
    <map_step map_field_source="TITLE"
              map_match="(\s+|\-)(A(|n|nd|s|t)|F(or|rom)|I(n|s)|O(f|n|r)|T(he|o)|With)\b"
              map_replace="$1\L$2"/>
    <map_step map_field_source="TITLE"
              map_match="([:;]\s+)([a-z])" map_replace="$1\u$2"/>
  </map>
  </maps>
</sourcemap>
</config>
```

The first two steps capitalize words at the beginning of the string (`^`), after whitespace (`\s`) or following a hyphen (`\-`). The third map down-cases selected words after whitespace or a hyphen. The last map capitalizes words following a colon or semi-colon (`[:;]`).

Here's a self-contained example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{biber.conf}
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
<sourcemap>
  <maps datatype="bibtex" map_overwrite="1">
  <map>
    <map_step map_field_source="TITLE"
              map_match="(^|\s)(\w+\S*w*)" map_replace="$1\u\L$2"/>
    <map_step map_field_source="TITLE"
              map_match="\-(\w+)" map_replace="\-\u\L$1"/>
    <map_step map_field_source="TITLE"
              map_match="(\s+|\-)(A(|n|nd|s|t)|B(ut|y)|F(or|rom)|I(n|s)|O(f|n|r)|T(he|o)|With)\b"
              map_replace="$1\L$2"/>
    <map_step map_field_source="TITLE"
              map_match="([:;]\s+)([a-z])" map_replace="$1\u$2"/>
  </map>
  </maps>
</sourcemap>
</config>
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{Smith2003,
  title = {This is an off-the-hook book title, but it doesn't have a subtitle},
  publisher = {Penguin},
  year = {2003},
  author = {Smith, James},
  address = {London}}
@ARTICLE{Doe1970,
  author = {H{\"a}user, {\O}rnulf},
  title = {{\O}rnulf H{\"a}user's letter to the editor: an $\alpha$-to-$\omega$
           summary of $\epsilon$--improvement},
  journal = {Great Journal},
  year = {1970},
  volume = {40},
  pages = {207-234}}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Audrey This is very useful. I have a lot of Arabic references that follow different rules of capitalization. Is it possible to excempt from your script `bib` entries that have `langid = {arabic}`?