# Implementation of "Title Case" in Bibtex

Tags: bibtex, capitalization

How is "title case" defined in bibtex? Which is the list of words *not* to  capitalize, and in which file is it defined? Is it possible to change it? I checked the `.bst` file, but apparently it's delegated to a function `change.case` whose definition I cannot find.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no "title case implementation" in BibTeX (or `biblatex`). There is a function to convert everything to sentence case (that is only the first word is capitalised, words wrapped in curly braces `{}` are left alone). Normally, you would give the title in Title Case wrapping only those words in braces that always have to be in uppercase and choose a style that does not change casing (if you need title case) or one that converts everything to sentence case. Example `title = {The Newest Discoveries of {NASA}, live from {Florida}}`.

Comment: Add `{....}` around the words that should definitely not be lower cased. Note that many journals have their own rules as to how titles should be cased. So you might like *Topology on Manifolds of Genus 2*, but the journal style dictates *Topology on manifolds of genus 2*. Only protect those that are actual names etc.

Comment: @moewe I see, so it's not implemented at all. Thanks. If you turn your comment into an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As far as I am aware, there is no BibTeX (nor any `biblatex`) style that implements a "convert to title case" macro/function (there was [a question a while back on how to achieve this with `biblatex`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/97698/35864), the answer shows a way to get started with such a macro in `biblatex` with Biber).

There is, however, a function to turn titles into sentence case (uppercase first letter of the first word, rest lowercased). It depends on the style whether or not this function is used. If your style applies sentence casing you will probably find a line like this in the `.bst` file `title "t" change.case$`.

So the rules is to give the titles in Title Case in the `.bib` file and have the bibliography style convert them to Sentence case if desired (cf. [What is the proper casing to use when storing titles in the bibliography database?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/439440/35864)).

Generally then, titles in `.bib` files should always be given in title case, where additionally words that *always have to be capitalised* in a certain way (names, acronyms, formulae etc.) are enclosed in curly braces `{}`.

Example

```
title = {From {Brouwer} to {Hilbert}: {The} Debate on the Foundations of Mathematics in the 1920s}
title = {{NASA} Ends Unmanned Launchings in {Florida}}
```

See also [BibTeX loses capitals when creating .bbl file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10772/35864), especially [Alexis' answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/140071/35864).

Comment: It is also a problem with the language: titles capitalisation in French is very different from English (roughly, only the first noun is capitalised, and the adjective if it precedes the noun). So directives should be written in .lbx file, for the case (!) of biblatex.

Comment: @Bernard It is indeed heavily language-dependent, in German, for example there is (normally) no difference between title and sentence case. Often it is very tedious though to implement a macro that converts sentence case to title case, so giving the title in title case and convert it to sentence case if need be, seems the way forward. (BTW. What is this about `.lbx` files?)

Comment: @ moewe: .lbx files contain language-dependent strings, punctuation and a few other things (for biblatex). so it's a natural idea | at least for me – to put something like "capitalisation patterns" in such a file. What makes it quite complex is that in an english bibliography,say , a title can be in german  or french. So this would require using a new field such as "title language".

Comment: @Bernard Well, you can already tell `biblatex` the title language (`langid` field; this feature will somewhat be extended in `biblatex` v. 3). But the point is that title casing macros require a whole lot of machinery that is not yet available, it is not just a matter of putting it into the `.lbx` file.

Comment: I see. 'Twas only a suggestion about what is conceptually interesting. I know real life is not so simple…

Answer (score 6):

The `change.case$` built-in function is described in the source (`texk/bibtex-x/bibtex-4.c` in TeX Live):

```
* The |built_in| function change.case$ pops the top two (string)
* literals; it changes the case of the second according to the
* specifications of the first, as follows.  (Note: The word `letters' in
* the next sentence refers only to those at brace-level~0, the top-most
* brace level; no other characters are changed, except perhaps for
* special characters, described shortly.)  If the first literal is the
* string t, it converts to lower case all letters except the very
* first character in the string, which it leaves alone, and except the
* first character following any |colon| and then nonnull |white_space|,
* which it also leaves alone; if it's the string l, it converts all
* letters to lower case; if it's the string u, it converts all
* letters to upper case; and if it's anything else, it complains and
* does no conversion.  It then pushes this resulting string.  If either
* type is incorrect, it complains and pushes the null string; however,
* if both types are correct but the specification string (i.e., the
* first string) isn't one of the legal ones, it merely pushes the second
* back onto the stack, after complaining.  (Another note: It ignores
* case differences in the specification string; for example, the strings
* t and T are equivalent for the purposes of this |built_in|
* function.)
```

That's complex and I didn't understand most of it, but in practice, I think that what needs to be remembered is that even after punctuation characters like ".", "!" or "?", the letters are converted to lower case by default... except after ":" (colon). Indeed,

```
title = {Test! Test? Test: Test. Test, Test}
```

in a .bib file yields:

```
\newblock Test! test? test: Test. test, test.
```

This only exception is rather strange and unexpected.

Comment: I found that ebracing the colon `Test{:} Test...` will work around this lone exception.  However, I would prefer an alternate version without a colon exception.

Answer (score 6):

This can be done in the following way, if you are willing to create a custom .bst file.  In your document, you need the following lines:

```
\usepackage{titlecaps}
\Addlcwords{the of into}
```

where the `\usepackage` makes use of the `titlecaps` package which has the `\titlecap` macro.  The `\Addlcwords` macro provides a list of words that should remain lower case and not be capitalized.

In your `.bst` file, you need to add a new macro:

```
FUNCTION {titlecap}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "\titlecap{" swap$ * "}" * }
  if$
}
```

The only thing left to do is to use it for the various document styles that you are formatting.  For example, a line in your style might have said something like this:

```
title ". " * output
```

which prints the title, concatenates a period and outputs the result.  Now, you would edit that to say:

```
title titlecap ". " * output
```

which will first apply the `titlecap` macro to `title`, before concatenating the period and outputting the result.  the invocation of `\titlecap` in the macro will capitalize the first letter of each word, except those in the exclusion list.   See package documentation at http://ctan.org/pkg/titlecaps.

Comment: Dear @Steven, is it okay for you to help me with my question here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/635720/use-titlecaps-package-with-achemso-bst 
regarding titlecap and achemso? Thank you.

Comment: @isend I may or may not be able to help, but you haven't provided enough information to lead to a solution.