# Getting `\textcite` to show only author last name when we have a single author

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I want to use the command `\textcite` in `biblatex`, but when the reference has a single author, the command shows the last name seperated by a comma from the first name. How can we let only the last name to be visible?

[image]

```
\begin{filecontents*}{sample.bib}
@online{lovelace2015low,
    author = {{Lovelace, Will}},
    title = {{Low SCR Wind Integration and Mitigation}},
    url = {http://www.cce.umn.edu/documents/CPE-Conferences/MIPSYCON-PowerPoints/2015/PGLowSCRWindGenerationInstabilityIdentificationandMitigation.pdf},
    organization = {Minnkota Power Cooperative},
    date = {2015-11-11},
    urldate = {2019-05-20}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}

\begin{document}

\textcite{lovelace2015low}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just write

```
author = {Lovelace, Will},
```

The double braces in `author = {{Lovelace, Will}},` stop Biber (and BibTeX) from parsing the name as the name of a person with family and given names. Instead the name is just interpreted as consisting of the family name "Lovelace, Will". This is desirable for corporate authors (see [Using a 'corporate author' in the "author" field of a bibliographic entry (spelling out the name in full)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10808/35864)), but not for people.

You can find out more about the valid input formats for names in [How should I type author names in a bib file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/557/35864).

I also remove the WYSIWYG bracing from the title field. See [Proper casing in citation/bibliography titles using biblatex/Biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20335/35864), [Capitalize words in Bibtex files: {Word} or {W}ord?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/474658/35864), [What is the proper casing to use when storing titles in the bibliography database?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/439440/35864) and more.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@online{lovelace2015low,
  author       = {Lovelace, Will},
  title        = {Low {SCR} Wind Integration and Mitigation},
  url          = {http://www.cce.umn.edu/documents/CPE-Conferences/MIPSYCON-PowerPoints/2015/PGLowSCRWindGenerationInstabilityIdentificationandMitigation.pdf},
  organization = {Minnkota Power Cooperative},
  date         = {2015-11-11},
  urldate      = {2019-05-20},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\textcite{lovelace2015low}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lovelace [Lov15]]

If you want the author to appear as

> Lovelace, Will

and not as

> Will Lovelace

in the bibliography, you need

```
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{translator}{sortname}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
```