# Change the case of publication titles in bibliographies created using Mendeley

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, mendeley

I would like to format the titles in my References such that they are in title case. However, when I generate the bibliography, only some references follow the desired format.

My .bib file is exported from Mendeley and the template I am using for the paper is from the `achemso` package. So far, I have tried following the advice from this post: [Biblatex changes capitalisation of titles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/430483/biblatex-changes-capitalisation-of-titles/430492#430492) . However, use of `biblatex` clashes with `mciteplus` even when this is commented out.

I've included an MWE, `.bib` script and image of the output. As you can see, Reference 1 is in the correct format but Reference 2 is not. Whilst it is possible to achieve title case in Reference 2 by editing the `.bib`, it is not feasible when there are many references.

Is it possible to make all titles in the References section title case easily and without affecting the rest of the document?

**MWE**

```
\RequirePackage[hyphens]{url}
\documentclass[journal=chreay,manuscript=review,layout=twocolumn]{achemso}

\usepackage{chemformula} % Formula subscripts using \ch{}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use modern font encodings
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}%adds hyperlinks to references in text. [hidelinks] removes blue boxes. 
\usepackage{mciteplus}
%\mciteErrorOnUnknownfalse
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}%Allows you to permanently fix figures.
%\sloppy%Makes sure that none of the text exceeds text width. Useful if have long chemical words.
%\usepackage[style=chem-acs, backend=biber]{biblatex}
%\addbibresource{library.bib}
%\DeclareFieldFormat{titlecase}{#1}


\newcommand*\mycommand[1]{\texttt{\emph{#1}}}

\title{Title}

\begin{document}
    
\section{Part 1}

Text \cite{ZapataHerrera2016}
Text \cite{Henglein1998}

\bibliography{library2}

\end{document}
```

**.bib**

```
@article{ZapataHerrera2016,
abstract = {Text},
author = {{Zapata Herrera}, Mario and Aizpurua, Javier and Kazansky, Andrey K. and Borisov, Andrei G.},
doi = {10.1021/acs.langmuir.6b00112},
issn = {15205827},
journal = {Langmuir},
number = {11},
pages = {2829--2840},
title = {{Plasmon Response and Electron Dynamics in Charged Metallic Nanoparticles}},
volume = {32},
year = {2016}
}
@article{Henglein1998,
abstract = {Text},
author = {Henglein, Arnim and Meisel, Dan},
doi = {10.1021/la981278w},
issn = {07437463},
journal = {Langmuir},
number = {26},
pages = {7392--7396},
title = {{Radiolytic control of the size of colloidal gold nanoparticles}},
volume = {14},
year = {1998}
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The 'correct way' to obtain Title Case in the bibliography is to input the title in Title Case in the `.bib` file (*only* protecting words that must not be lowercased with curly braces) and using a bibliography style that does not apply sentence casing. I am not aware of any LaTeX/BibTeX-based solution to obtain Title Case from Sentence cased input that would be widely used. In your case the correct input of the titles would be `title = {Plasmon Response and Electron Dynamics in Charged Metallic Nanoparticles},` and `title = {Radiolytic Control of the Size of Colloidal Gold Nanoparticles},`

Comment: The bibliography style you are using does not apply sentence casing, so one you give the input in Title Case as recommended you should be good.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10772/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/166616/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/439440/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/474658/35864, for some background and more hints

Comment: @moewe thanks for the advice. In my report I have a few hundred references so I would love to find a simpler solution to apply the title case if possible. Are you able to say why ```mciteplus``` clashes with the ```biblatex``` section I have commented out in the MWE? From the link I posted, it looks like there is a workaround but when I try an error message appears saying ```biblatex``` is incompatible with ```mciteplus```.

Comment: It's not (only) `mciteplus` that is the problem here, the class loads `natbib` which is fundamentally incompatible with `biblatex`. But a switch to `biblatex` wouldn't help here anyway: It's the same story there. `biblatex` can only convert from Title Case to Sentence case. So again you have to save your titles in Title Case and have them converted to Sentence case by the style if desired (which it is not in this case). I'm afraid in the LaTeX/BibTeX/`biblatex` world the only solution is to make sure the input is in Title Case.