# Custom .bst file: change.case$ does not work

Tags: bibtex, custom-bib

I am using a custom .bst file and `title "t" change.case$` does not seem to work. It changes the cast to lower or upper when used with parameters `"u"` or `"l"`.

My `format.title` function:

```
FUNCTION {format.title}
{ "title" bibinfo.check
  title "t" change.case$
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$ 
    {
      "\enquote{" swap$ *
      "}, " *
    }
  if$
}
```

and the output:
[image: pdflatex output]

**Another example:**
In .bib file the title is
`title = {Grandmaster level in StarCraft II using multi-agent reinforcement learning}`

and the output produced:
[image: example 2]
It looks like it is changing it to a sentence case and not title case.

**Another example**
`title = {the title of the work}`
and the output is:
[image: example 3]

But when I change a line in `format.title` to `title "u" change.case$` I get:
[image: example4]

This is very strange behaviour. Do you know how to fix it?

EDIT:
The expected output is "The Title of the Work" ([see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case#Case_styles)). I want to achieve the title case.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `"t" change.case$` does “title casing”: all letters are made lower-case, except for the first one. The output seems correct.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik the term "title case" is also used for _A mixed-case style with all words capitalised, except for certain subsets (particularly articles and short prepositions and conjunctions)_ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case#Case_styles).

Comment: `"t" change.case$` does what I would call 'sentence case'. It transforms everything but the first letter (and the first letter after a colon plus a space) to lowercase. The standard solution is to input the fields in Title Case in the `.bib` file and let BibTeX convert it to sentence case if required. (cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/166616/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/439440/35864)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"t" change.case$` applies what I (and Wikipedia) would call 'sentence case'. It converts all but the first letter (and the first letter after a colon followed by at least one space), which is left unchanged, to lowercase.

There is no built-in BibTeX function to apply Title Case in the sense of the Wikipedia definition and I'm not aware of a comprehensive contributed BibTeX (or indeed `biblatex`) solution for Title Casing. See also [Implementation of "Title Case" in Bibtex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/166616/35864).

The way Sentence case and Title Case are normally handled in `.bib` files is as follows

- Titles are given in the `.bib` file in Title Case with words that always need to be uppercase (proper nouns, acronyms, ...) protected in curly braces.
- If desired a bibliography style can convert the title into Sentence case, otherwise it is shown as input (i.e. in Title Case).

See also the discussion in [What is the proper casing to use when storing titles in the bibliography database?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/439440/35864).

---

In your case you would write

```
title = {The Title of the Work},
title = {Grandmaster Level in {StarCraft II} Using Multi-agent Reinforcement Learning},
```

in the `.bib` file and just write

```
title
```

without any `change.case$` call in the `.bst` file.