# Bibtex & formatting CSL title

Tags: bibtex, pdf, pandoc, pandoc-citeproc

I found a way to use `pandoc-citeproc` to create a PDF from a markdown file with references in Bibtex and citation with footnote-like references using an edited `ieee.csl` file. I used `misc`and put the (archive) references in `title` field. I had to put the text in double curly brackets to not have the case etc altered. Is there a way I can put formatting information (bold, italic) in the bibtex file while keeping all info in the title field? Or is the only way to try to split my references in several fields so I can format it with the CSL?

Comment: The case change of English titles is probably an expected feature of your bibliography style (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10772/35864). If you are writing in a language where English case change rules should not apply, have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/483615/35864. The `.bib` file usually should not contain any formatting markup. It should contain the raw data, formatting is left to the bibliography style. It should also be possible to format your bibliography with CSL, but you'll have probably more luck asking about this on a more pandoc-specific site.