# How can I automatically capitalize significant words in my bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib, capitalization

I'm using BibTex with natbib and the `abbrvnat` bibliography style. By default, it converts all but the first letter and `{}`-protected letters to lower case. I would like to automatically title-case my bibliography. Specifically, I would like to capitalize the first letter of each word unless it is in a list of given insignificant words. Can this be done automatically without changing the bibtex file?

Comment: BibTeX (and `biblatex`) can only go the other way of converting to sentence case. Conversion to title case is tricky in both BibTeX (mainly because of restrictions on the number of strings and awkward string handling in general) and TeX (because TeX was not written for string manipulation, but there are https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/103838/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34796/35864). But even then you would have to tell the `.bst` style to use one of these methods. Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/97698/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/439440/35864