# Main Letter Caps "biblatex-chicago"

Tags: biblatex-chicago

My tags are follows:

**test.tex**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[natbib,authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}%

\addbibresource{test.bib}

\makeatletter
\AtEveryBibitem{\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\citet{baker_tenenbaum_saxe06} and \citet{baker_saxe_tenenbaum09}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

**test.bib**

```
@inproceedings{baker_tenenbaum_saxe06,
Author = {C. L. Baker and J. Tenenbaum and R. Saxe},
Booktitle = {Advances in neural information processing systems},
Date-Added = {2014-01-30 12:16:28 +0100},
Date-Modified = {2014-02-01 00:11:49 +0100},
Publisher = {Cambridge, MA: MIT Press},
Title = {Bayesian models of human action understanding},
Volume = {18},
Year = {2006}}

@article{baker_saxe_tenenbaum09,
Author = {C. L. Baker and J. Tenenbaum and R. Saxe},
Date-Added = {2014-01-30 12:11:35 +0100},
Date-Modified = {2014-02-05 23:44:19 +0100},
Journal = {Cognition},
Number = {3},
Pages = {329--349},
Title = {Action understanding as inverse planning},
Volume = {113},
Year = {2009}}
```

[image]

Above codes are working fine, is it possible to get the marked letters are in caps by auto? (It comes in uppercase if I change in .bib file) Please advise...

Comment: You have to use title case in your `bib` file. It's possible to convert title case to sentence case, but not sentence case to title case. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/166619/87678

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/97960/87678

Comment: @DavidPurton Much Thanks... Will check it....

Comment: @DavidPurton Do you want to type up a quick answer here, so the question can be marked as answered?

Comment: @moewe, I think it should a duplicate. Maybe of the second question?

Comment: @DavidPurton and `moewe` given suggestion fine for me....Thanks a lot...

Comment: @moewe Thanks, will check as you suggested....