# What's wrong with my bibliography?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, xetex

I am running my thesis.tex file, but something strange persists. It said

```
./thesis.tex:96: Extra }, or forgotten $.
<recently read> }

l.96 ...hy[heading=bibintoc, title={参考文献}]
```

I went back to where the error points to,

```
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc, title={参考文献}]
```

But it's my belief that there is nothing wrong in there.

What's the real problem of it, and how to fix it.

I used `XeLaTex- BibTex-XeLaTex` to compile the file, and I used `Teashop 3.61.`

Updated: as suggested by @Johannes_B, the problem is in bib file.

I provide the trouble bib entry as follows.

```
@article{Shen2010,
  doi= {10.1016/j.automatica.2010.06.025},
  url= {http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.automatica.2010.06.025},
  year = {2010},
  month= oct,
  publisher= {Elsevier {BV}},
  volume= {46},
  number= {10},
  pages= {1682--1688},
  author= {Bo Shen and Zidong Wang and Y.S. Hung},
  title= {Distributed ${H}_\infty$-consensus filtering in sensor networks with multiple missing measurements: The finite-horizon case},
  journal= {Automatica}
}
```

and I setting option of `biblatex` as

```
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp,doi=false,url=false,firstinits=true,backend=biber,sorting=none,maxnames=3,minnames=3]{biblatex}
```

Comment: There is something going on in your database file which needs correction. You might have something like `Al_2O_3` in there causing the math error.

Comment: You mean in the `.bib` files?

Comment: Yes, in the bib-files.

Comment: Thank you so much, I just found it's the `${H}_\infty$` in the title of the bib caused the trouble. If I delete it, all the files work well, but I really want this term appeared in my title. How to do it?

Comment: Please show us the whole entry. Maybe even a minimal working example.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my question, it currently contains the whole entry.

Comment: No problem here, so a [minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/index.html) is in order.

Comment: I found it's the command ` \DeclareFieldFormat{titlecase}{\MakeSentenceCase*{#1}}` triggered the problem.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20349/44227 This answer addressed my concerns.