# Letting strings start with a capital letter

Tags: indexing, strings, capitalization, text-manipulation

I am writing a small book and try to build up an index reference. To make it a little easier I wrote a small script that enables my to type a word and also add it to the index:

```
\newcommand{\toindex}[1]{\index{#1}\indexlayout{#1}}
```

However this results in words added to the index that don't start with a capital letter. This makes the index looks a little bit dirty. Is there a way to generate a string out of parameter `#1` that switches the first character to its uppercase counterpart and leave the rest of the string the same?

Comment: Have you read this: [Command to uppercase the first letter of each word in a sentence](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7992/5764)?

Comment: Thanks! Nearly the same, but it looks all words get an uppercase character, I will try to convert the script that only the first character gets an uppercase.

Comment: furthermore something goes wrong when this script tries to manipulate strings with mathematics inside (I expect the $-signs generate some problems) like $n$-army problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would define two commands (actually one command with a *-form):

```
\newcommand\toindex{\@ifstar{\@dblarg{\@toindexs}}{\@toindex}}
\def\@toindexs[#1]#2{\indexlayout{#2}\index{#1@#2}}
\newcommand\@toindex[2][]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \indexlayout{#2}%
    \begingroup
    \@splitword#2\@nil%
    \uppercase\expandafter{%
      \expandafter\def\expandafter\@initial\expandafter{\@first}}%
    \toks0=\expandafter{\@initial}%
    \toks2=\expandafter{\@rest}%
    \edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\index{\the\toks0 \the\toks2 }}\x
  \else
    \indexlayout{#2}\index{#1}
  \fi
}
\def\@splitword#1#2\@nil{\def\@first{#1}\def\@rest{#2}}
\makeatletter
```

For entries such as `$n$-entry` you would use `\toindex*[nentry]{$n$-entry}`, for `word` you can use `\toindex{word}`. The optional argument can be used in either case.

For `\toindex*` the optional argument is used for collation; it's actually more than optional: `makeindex` would sort `\index{$n$-entry}` among symbols.

For `\toindex` the optional argument can be used for the cases when the word to be indexed is special, for instance

```
\toindex[equipe@\'Equipe]{\'equipe}
```

However, I don't see the necessity to capitalize words in the index. Look at the TeXbook, for an example. `:)`

Comment: Well it's not that much the fact that an index starts with a capital letter, but more the fact that when you use an item twice (with lowercase and uppercase), two items are added to the index...