# Command to uppercase the first letter of a maths command

Tags: math-mode, macros, amsmath, babel, capitalization

This question is a bit similar to [Command to uppercase the first letter of each word in a sentence](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7992/command-to-uppercase-the-first-letter-of-each-word-in-a-sentence).

What I want is to build a new command for being used just at math mode, using the `\DeclareMathOperator` command available at `amsmath` package.

The new command I would like to define is the existing command `\max` but with its first letter in uppercase.

Notice that the final result of `\max` command depends on changes made by `babel` package, for instance. In my case, I would place my `\DeclareMathOperator` sentence *after* calling `babel`.

Is there a quick way to do this?

In case it's needed, this is a simple example of using `\DeclareMathOperator`:

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\argmax}{\arg\max}
```

EDIT:

What I am trying to say is that `\DeclareMathOperator{\Max}{Max}` is not a valid solution for me, because what I want is *the same thing produced by `\max`* (just with the first letter in uppercase), *but* taking into account that the result produced by `\max` depends on the effect of other packages (for example, calling `babel` with `spanish` option would produce "máx" for `\max` and not "max"). So, it is not so simple as it could seem...

Comment: since the suggested approach doesn't solve your problem, please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows what's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite a generic solution, as it assumes that the first letter is unique in the operator name. The `\relax` are perhaps a bit optional I am always confused about when I should put some or not ;-)

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[english,spanish]{babel}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\Max{\@tempcnta=\mathcode`\m\relax
\mathcode`\m=\mathcode`\M\max\mathcode`\m=\@tempcnta\relax}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \begin{equation*}
    \max_0^\infty = \Max_0^\infty \Max\nolimits_0^\infty m M 
  \end{equation*}
\selectlanguage{english}
  \begin{equation*}
    \max_0^\infty = \Max_0^\infty \Max\nolimits_0^\infty m M
  \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

---

Thanks to egreg for his comment(s). After having temporarily incorporated his simplification (of the code of my initial proposal) to the extension I am now proposing, I now return to the original thing, but also incorporate the later improvements signaled by `egreg`.

The same restriction as above applies (the operator name should contain its initial letter only once).

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[english,spanish]{babel}
\pagestyle{empty}

\makeatletter

\def\Tr@nsmogrify#1#2.{\expandafter\newcommand\csname #1#2\endcsname
{\mathchardef\Tr@ns@temp=\mathcode\lccode`#1\relax
\mathcode\lccode`#1=\mathcode`#1\lowercase{\csname#1#2\endcsname}%
\mathcode\lccode`#1=\Tr@ns@temp\relax}}

\@for\x:=Sin,Cos,Max,Min,Lim,Limsup,Liminf,Inf\do{%
\expandafter\Tr@nsmogrify \x.}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
  \begin{align*}
\min_0^\infty &= \Min_0^\infty\\
\min\nolimits_0^\infty &= \Min\nolimits_0^\infty\\
\max_0^\infty &= \Max_0^\infty\\
\lim_{x\to\infty} &= \Lim_{x\to\infty}\\
\liminf_{x\to\infty} &= \Liminf_{x\to\infty}\\
\limsup_{x\to\infty} &= \Limsup_{x\to\infty}\\
\inf_{x\in A} &= \Inf_{x\in A}\\
\sin^2 x +\cos^2 x  &= \Sin^2 x +\Cos^2 x \\
\limsup_{x\to\infty} &= \Limsup_{x\to\infty}\\
m,M,l,L&,s,S,c,C
  \end{align*}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\selectlanguage{english}%
  \begin{align*}
\min_0^\infty &= \Min_0^\infty\\
\min\nolimits_0^\infty &= \Min\nolimits_0^\infty\\
\max_0^\infty &= \Max_0^\infty\\
\lim_{x\to\infty} &= \Lim_{x\to\infty}\\
\liminf_{x\to\infty} &= \Liminf_{x\to\infty}\\
\limsup_{x\to\infty} &= \Limsup_{x\to\infty}\\
\inf_{x\in A} &= \Inf_{x\in A}\\
\sin^2 x +\cos^2 x  &= \Sin^2 x +\Cos^2 x \\
\limsup_{x\to\infty} &= \Limsup_{x\to\infty}\\
m,M,l,L&,s,S,c,C
  \end{align*}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Here is the result:

[image: PNG image with english and spanish operators with first letter made uppercase]

Addendum:

The above definitions make `\Xyzt` behave like `\xyzt` with respect to the positions of  *limits*, in inline as well as display style. But there *is* a difference: `\[\sin\limits_a^b\]` or `$\sin\limits_a^b$` do *not* put the `a` and `b` in *limits* positions, whereas `\[\Sin\limits_a^b\]` and `$\Sin\limits_a^b$` do. I would call this an unintended feature rather than a bug! This is illustrated by the following:

[image: different behaviors of limits]

Note the asymmetry of behavior of the `amsmath` operators `\sin` and `\min`. Whereas for the first `\limits` does nothing, for the second `\nolimits`  does work. I will not qualify this as a bug of `amsmath` (or rather `amsopn.sty`), as there must be reasons beyond me, but I had never realized that until now.

PS: obviously the above image comes from a source with `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}` but I  checked that the exact same behavior is observed without any loading of babel. Note also that `\sin` and `\min` in `amsopn.sty` are not defined via `\DeclareMathOperator`, respectively `\DeclareMathOperator*`, but only by some part of the code of these macros, but this is another not relevant detail.

PS2: as a matter of fact the `[spanish]{babel}` defined operator names behave differently from the analogous `amsmath` provided names with respect to limits.

[image: examples of operator names with \limits]

Comment: ``\newcommand\Max{\mathop{\mathcode`m=\mathcode`M \max}\displaylimits}`` is easier, isn't it? By the way, your `\relax` is not needed: `\@tempcnta` is unexpandable, so it stops the search for a number.

Comment: @egreg: thanks. See my edited reply for an extension to my initial proposal. And what is the rôle of `\displaylimits`?

Comment: The problem with this general definition is that every new operator will receive limits above and below in display math mode, because it's the default setting for a `\mathop`: try `\[\Sin^{2}x\]`. In my suggestion `\displaylimits` is not really necessary; but the proper definition for `\Sin` would be ``\mathop{\mathcode`s=\mathcode`S \sin}\nolimits``

Comment: @egreg: I remember now these `limits` things (always found this terminology chosen by Knuth weird). Well, I will revert to using `\@tempcnta` then, or perhaps I can use `\mathcode0`. Ok, let's put it in.

Comment: It may be a nice exercise, but I've nowhere seen "Sin" for the sine function. ;-)

Comment: @egreg: Sin was for a proof of concept... I might provide a math definition if only my brain recovers and stops playing with TeX macros! ;-)

Comment: Instead of ``\mathcode0=\mathcode`#1`` I would use ``\mathchardef\jfbu@temp=\mathcode`#1`` to store the code and ``\mathcode`#1=\jfbu@temp`` at the end. And, of course, `\expandafter\Tr@nsmogrify\x.` instead of `\edef\act{\noexpand\Tr@nsmogrify\x.}\act`.

Comment: oh well. I had copied the `\edef\act` thing from some bits of more complicated code where the `\expandafter` would not have sufficed. Thanks again. I incorporate your remarks.

Comment: By the way, I forgot that the sine function is denoted sen in spanish. And I am extremely interested to discover in spanish.ldf that the `\tg` and `\cotg` macros are defined. For years I lament the fact that in France, `tan` and `cotan` have been used in schools rather than `tg` and `cotg`, the main reason being that it is the way pocket calculators appear. And among professors and researchers in math, it is amazing how many do not know how to define a `\tg` macro. I now dream of a `\let\tan\undefined\DeclareMathOperator{\tan}{tg}` in `frenchb.ldf`...

Comment: @jfbu Thank you very much!! I know my question was a little bit strange, and it can be solved in several ways, but this one is very nice. Thanks.

Comment: @VicentGiner-Bosch thank you for the problem which got me very much interested the other day! but do I deserve your vote? ;-) because now that I look closely I see that \Inf did not work, this is normal as my method in that case would have replaced i by I, but the i had already been transformed by babel into í ...

Comment: @jbfu It's OK, I see what you mean, but anyway your solution is good enough for me. Thank you again! :)

Answer (score 3):

There's no real possibility to simply uppercase the first letter. You have two strategies available for defining a *new* operator.  I'll make examples for a three language document.

### Strategy 1

Define a default string and auxiliary strings for the languages where the form must change.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[english,italian,spanish]{babel}

% the new operator
\DeclareMathOperator{\Max}{\Maxname}
% default string
\newcommand{\defaultMaxname}{Max}
\let\Maxname\defaultMaxname 
% English and Italian want "Max"
% Spanish wants a different name, "Máx"
\newcommand{\spanishMaxname}{M\acute{a}x}
\addto\extrasspanish{\let\Maxname\spanishMaxname}
\addto\noextrasspanish{\let\Maxname\defaultMaxname}
%%%

\begin{document}
Esto es $\Max$

\begin{otherlanguage}{english}
This is $\Max$
\end{otherlanguage}

\selectlanguage{italian}    
Questo \`e $\Max$

\end{document}
```

The output will be

> Esto es Máx
>   This is Max
>   Questo è Max

However, `otherlanguage*` and `\foreignlanguage` won't change the behavior and in those contexts you'll get "Máx" as in the default language, in this case Spanish.

### Strategy 2

Define explicitly the string for all languages you plan to use.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[english,italian,spanish]{babel}


\DeclareMathOperator*{\Max}{\Maxname}
\newcommand{\englishMaxname}{Max}
\newcommand{\italianMaxname}{Max}
\newcommand{\spanishMaxname}{M\acute{a}x}

\let\Maxname\englishMaxname % default
\addto\extrasenglish{\let\Maxname\englishMaxname}
\addto\extrasitalian{\let\Maxname\italianMaxname}
\addto\extrasspanish{\let\Maxname\spanishMaxname}

\begin{document}
Esto es $\Max$

\begin{otherlanguage*}{english}
This is $\Max$
\end{otherlanguage*}

\foreignlanguage{italian}{Questo \`e $\Max$}

\end{document}
```

The output will be

> Esto es Máx
>   This is Max
>   Questo è Max

exactly as before, but also `otherlanguage*` and `\foreignlanguage` will respect the language setting.

---

Comment: And what if I would like to do it sort of language-independent??

Comment: @VicentGiner-Bosch What do you mean? *This* is language independent: the behavior changes when you change the language. The Spanish module for `babel` defines its own version of `\max`. I'll edit the answer anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer a clean definition of `\Max`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\Max}{Max}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
\max_0^\infty = \Max_0^\infty
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Patch solution

This example defines `\Max` by copying the definition from `\max` via package `letltxmacro`, because `\max` was defined via `\DeclareRobustCommand`. Then `max` is exchanged by `Max` in the internal macro via package `etoolbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\LetLtxMacro\Max\max
\patchcmd\Max{max}{Max}{}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
\max_0^\infty = \Max_0^\infty
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

### Update: With Spanish accents

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[english,spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\DeclareMathOperator*{\en@Max}{Max}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\es@Max}{M\es@op@ac{a}x}
\addto\es@operators{%
  \let\Max\es@Max
}
\providecommand*{\nomathspanish}{}
\addto\nomathspanish{%
  \let\Max\en@Max
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Spanish:
\begin{gather*}
\max_0^\infty = \Max_0^\infty
\end{gather*}

\selectlanguage{english}
English:
\begin{gather*}
\max_0^\infty = \Max_0^\infty
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: that doesn't solve my problem, as `\max` doesn't produce "max" but "máx" when using `babel` with `spanish` as an option. So what I would like to achieve is a definition that is valid for all possible transformations that `babel`(and/or other packages) could perform on the original `\max` command.

Comment: @egreg, I'm sorry but I think I was specific enough, as I mentioned `babel` on my question. Anyway, I am going to edit it in order to make it clearer, if possible.

Comment: @VicentGiner-Bosch If you just want to get rid of the math operator redefinitions of `babel`'s `spanish`: `\makeatletter\let\es@operators\relax\makeatother`.

Comment: no, I don't want to get rid of it, but take it into account!