# Glossaries Capitalize Every First Letter

Tags: glossaries

How can I get the `\Gls{...}` command to capitalize the first letter of **EACH** word, not just the first word?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\newacronym{tla}{TLA}{three lettered acronym}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\glsfirst{tla}

\Glsfirst{tla}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What about this answer? Does it help or give you some insight? http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78217/31058

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`\Gls`-like commands use `\makefirstuc` to capitalize only the first letter of a sentence.

I've redefined the meaning of `\makefirstuc` to be the same of `\capitalisewords` which instead capitalizes all words in a sentence.

So, add this in the preamble

```
\makeatletter
\let\oldmakefirstuc\makefirstuc
\renewcommand*{\makefirstuc}[1]{%
  \def\gls@add@space{}%
  \mfu@capitalisewords#1 \@nil\mfu@endcap
}
\def\mfu@capitalisewords#1 #2\mfu@endcap{%
  \def\mfu@cap@first{#1}%
  \def\mfu@cap@second{#2}%
  \gls@add@space
  \oldmakefirstuc{#1}%
  \def\gls@add@space{ }%
  \ifx\mfu@cap@second\@nnil
    \let\next@mfu@cap\mfu@noop
  \else
    \let\next@mfu@cap\mfu@capitalisewords
  \fi
  \next@mfu@cap#2\mfu@endcap
}
\makeatother
```

and everything should be as you want.

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeatletter
\let\oldmakefirstuc\makefirstuc
\renewcommand*{\makefirstuc}[1]{%
  \def\gls@add@space{}%
  \mfu@capitalisewords#1 \@nil\mfu@endcap
}
\def\mfu@capitalisewords#1 #2\mfu@endcap{%
  \def\mfu@cap@first{#1}%
  \def\mfu@cap@second{#2}%
  \gls@add@space
  \oldmakefirstuc{#1}%
  \def\gls@add@space{ }%
  \ifx\mfu@cap@second\@nnil
    \let\next@mfu@cap\mfu@noop
  \else
    \let\next@mfu@cap\mfu@capitalisewords
  \fi
  \next@mfu@cap#2\mfu@endcap
}
\makeatother

\newacronym{tla}{TLA}{three lettered acronym}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\glsfirst{tla}

\Glsfirst{tla}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This is excellent, how would it be possible to ignore words such as: to, or, for, the, and, etc...

Comment: @ADP this is not simple at all, I think. And I haven't any idea at the moment...

Comment: This is a bit of a hack, I am sure, however it works... `\newacronym{tla}{TLA}{three~lettered acronym}` prevents the 'lettered' word from being capitalized. Therefore, in each definition, joining 'and', 'to', 'for' etc... to the previous words via `~` does the job.

Comment: Why does Latex "programming" have to look to chaotic?!