# Capitalize the first letter for EACH word with glossaries-extra package

Tags: glossaries, glossaries-extra

How to capitalize the first letter for EACH word in a glossary using the `glossaries-extra` package?

I came across [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134493/glossaries-capitalize-every-first-letter) but it uses the `glossaries` package.

I also tried `\glsentrytitlecase{<label>}{long}` but it didn't

1. make the glossary hyperlinked
2. include the glossary in the parentheses at the end, e.g., (ESs) in the MWE below

Basically, what I want is similar to `\Gls` but make capitalize the first letter for EACH word instead of the first word only.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries-extra}
\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long}
\newacronym
[
  description={Evolutionary Strategies},
  longplural={evolutionary strategies}
]
{es}{ES}{evolutionary strategy}
\makeglossaries


\begin{document}
\printglossary[type=acronym,title={List of Acronyms}]

\glsentrytitlecase{es}{long}.

\glspl{es}.

\Glspl{es}.

\glsentrytitlecase{es}{longpl}.

\end{document}
```

---

Update:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[acronym,automake]{glossaries-extra}

\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd*{\myGls}{\@gls@hyp@opt\@myGls}
\newcommand*{\@myGls}[2][]{%
  \new@ifnextchar[{\@myGls@{#1}{#2}}{\@myGls@{#1}{#2}[]}%
}
\def\@myGls@#1#2[#3]{%
  \glsdoifexists{#2}%
  {%
    \let\do@gls@link@checkfirsthyper\@gls@link@checkfirsthyper
    \let\glsifplural\@secondoftwo
    \let\glscapscase\@secondofthree
    \def\glscustomtext{%
    {%
    \ecapitalisewords{\glsentrylong{#2}}#3\space%
    \firstacronymfont(\glsentryshort{#2})}%
    }
    \def\glsinsert{#3}%
    \def\@glo@text{\csname gls@\glstype @entryfmt\endcsname}%
    \@gls@link[#1]{#2}{\@glo@text}%
    \ifKV@glslink@local
      \glslocalunset{#2}%
    \else
      \glsunset{#2}%
    \fi
  }%
  \glspostlinkhook
}

\newrobustcmd*{\myGlspl}{\@gls@hyp@opt\@myGlspl}
\newcommand*{\@myGlspl}[2][]{%
  \new@ifnextchar[{\@myGlspl@{#1}{#2}}{\@myGlspl@{#1}{#2}[]}%
}
\def\@myGlspl@#1#2[#3]{%
  \glsdoifexists{#2}%
  {%
    \let\do@gls@link@checkfirsthyper\@gls@link@checkfirsthyper
    \let\glsifplural\@firstoftwo
    \let\glscapscase\@secondofthree
    \def\glscustomtext{%
    {%
    \ecapitalisewords{\glsentrylongpl{#2}}#3\space%
    \firstacronymfont(\glsentryshortpl{#2})}%
    }
    \def\glsinsert{#3}%
    \def\@glo@text{\csname gls@\glstype @entryfmt\endcsname}%
    \@gls@link[#1]{#2}{\@glo@text}%
    \ifKV@glslink@local
      \glslocalunset{#2}%
    \else
      \glsunset{#2}%
    \fi
  }%
  \glspostlinkhook
}
\makeatother

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long}

\newacronym
[
    description=Evolutionary Strategy,
    longplural=evolutionary strategies
]
{es}{ES}{evolutionary strategy}
\makeglossaries


\begin{document}
\printglossary[type=acronym,title={List of Acronyms}]

textbf{Singular:}

blablbla \gls{es}.

blablbla \glsxtrfull{es}.

blablbla \Gls{es}.

blablbla \Glsxtrfull{es}.

blablbla \myGls{es}.

blablbla \glsentrytitlecase{es}{long}.


\vspace*{1cm}


\textbf{Plural:}

blablbla \glspl{es}.

blablbla \glsxtrfullpl{es}.

blablbla \Glspl{es}.

blablbla \Glsxtrfullpl{es}.

blablbla \myGlspl{es}.

blablbla \glsentrytitlecase{es}{longpl}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `glossaries-extra` package is just an extension to the glossaries package. The basic commands will be same for both packages. The thread you mentioned is working in your case.

Comment: @Tom Are you sure? If I change the line `\usepackage{glossaries}` to `\usepackage{glossaries-extra}`, it doesn't produce the same result...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution. Notice the comments in the code. If you wanna the second use to display the short form, uncomment those comments. Otherwise it will always display the full form. Add `\myGlspl` to deal with plural form.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym,automake]{glossaries-extra}

\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd*{\myGls}{\@gls@hyp@opt\@myGls}
\newcommand*{\@myGls}[2][]{%
  \new@ifnextchar[{\@myGls@{#1}{#2}}{\@myGls@{#1}{#2}[]}%
}
\def\@myGls@#1#2[#3]{%
  \glsdoifexists{#2}%
  {%
    \let\do@gls@link@checkfirsthyper\@gls@link@checkfirsthyper
    \let\glsifplural\@secondoftwo
    \let\glscapscase\@secondofthree
    \def\glscustomtext{%
    \ifglsused{#2}
    {\acronymfont\glsentryshort{#2}#3}
    {%
    \ecapitalisewords{\glsentrylong{#2}}#3\space%
    \firstacronymfont(\glsentryshort{#2})}%
    }%
    \def\glsinsert{#3}%
    \def\@glo@text{\csname gls@\glstype @entryfmt\endcsname}%
    \@gls@link[#1]{#2}{\@glo@text}%
    \ifKV@glslink@local
      \glslocalunset{#2}%
    \else
      \glsunset{#2}%
    \fi
  }%
  \glspostlinkhook
}

\newrobustcmd*{\myGlspl}{\@gls@hyp@opt\@myGlspl}
\newcommand*{\@myGlspl}[2][]{%
  \new@ifnextchar[{\@myGlspl@{#1}{#2}}{\@myGlspl@{#1}{#2}[]}%
}
\def\@myGlspl@#1#2[#3]{%
  \glsdoifexists{#2}%
  {%
    \let\do@gls@link@checkfirsthyper\@gls@link@checkfirsthyper
    \let\glsifplural\@firstoftwo
    \let\glscapscase\@secondofthree
    \def\glscustomtext{%
    \ifglsused{#2}%
    {\acronymfont\glsentryshortpl{#2}#3}
    {%
    \ecapitalisewords{\glsentrylongpl{#2}}#3\space%
    \firstacronymfont(\glsentryshortpl{#2})}%
    }%
    \def\glsinsert{#3}%
    \def\@glo@text{\csname gls@\glstype @entryfmt\endcsname}%
    \@gls@link[#1]{#2}{\@glo@text}%
    \ifKV@glslink@local
      \glslocalunset{#2}%
    \else
      \glsunset{#2}%
    \fi
  }%
  \glspostlinkhook
}
\makeatother

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}

\newacronym{tla}{TLA}{three lettered acronym}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\printglossary[type=acronym,title={List of Acronyms}]

\myGls{tla}

\myGlspl{tla}

\Gls{tla}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to keep the result of `\Gls` as it is (only the first letter of the first word is capitalized)?

Comment: Do you wanna a new command did similar thing as `\Gls` but capitalized each words?

Comment: Yes. and I would like to keep the functionality of `\Gls` intact. With the code you provided, the result of `\Gls` also capitalizes the first letter of EACH word instead of only the FIRST word as it is.

Comment: @hmhuang I found a way to do that. I have a question for you. Do you wanna the second use of the command to display the short form or it doesn't matter. See the new edits in my answer.

Comment: I need the short form as from the second use.

Comment: How to deal with the plural cases?

Comment: @hmhuang Add to the answer.

Comment: Thanks. Could you directly provide the code that can show the short form in the second use? I am not sure which line to uncomment...

Comment: @hmhuang I have already uncomment those. The code in answer should did what you want.

Comment: I just spotted a tiny issue with the code: The space in front of the `\myGls` and `\myGlspl\` is larger than the normal one. Could you please fix it? Thanks! (Please see the updated post)

Comment: If you complete copy my code it won’t have any space in front. Notice every %in the code is necessary to prevent extra space happen

Comment: @hmhuang Sorry, that's my fault,. It was missing two % signs in the code. Thank you for point this out. I have fixed it. See if it works in your case.