# xmakefirstuc combined with MakeTextLowercase

Tags: strings, xstring

I am trying to convert a string as in the example, with all lowercase characters except the first. However, `xmakefirstuc` does not like me that much. Here's my MWE:

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}
\newcommand{\howtodothis}[1]{%
    \StrSubstitute{#1}{ }{-}[\mylong]%
    \xmakefirstuc{\MakeTextLowercase{\mylong}}\\%
    \xmakefirstuc\expandafter{\MakeTextLowercase{\mylong}}\\%
    \xmakefirstuc{\expandafter\MakeTextLowercase{\mylong}}\\%
    \xmakefirstuc{\MakeTextLowercase\expandafter{\mylong}}\\%
    \xmakefirstuc{\MakeTextLowercase{\expandafter\mylong}}\\%
    \xmakefirstuc\expandafter\relax{\MakeTextLowercase{\mylong}}\\%
    \xmakefirstuc{\expandafter\relax\MakeTextLowercase{\mylong}}\\%
    \xmakefirstuc{\MakeTextLowercase\expandafter\relax{\mylong}}\\%
    \xmakefirstuc{\MakeTextLowercase{\expandafter\relax\mylong}}\\%
    \expandafter\xmakefirstuc{\MakeTextLowercase{\mylong}}\\%
    \expandafter\xmakefirstuc\expandafter{\MakeTextLowercase{\mylong}}\\%
    \expandafter\xmakefirstuc{\expandafter\MakeTextLowercase{\mylong}}\\%
    \expandafter\xmakefirstuc{\MakeTextLowercase\expandafter{\mylong}}\\%
    \expandafter\xmakefirstuc{\MakeTextLowercase{\expandafter\mylong}}\\%
    \expandafter\xmakefirstuc\expandafter\relax{\MakeTextLowercase{\mylong}}\\%
    \expandafter\xmakefirstuc{\expandafter\relax\MakeTextLowercase{\mylong}}\\%
    \expandafter\xmakefirstuc{\MakeTextLowercase\expandafter\relax{\mylong}}\\%
    \expandafter\xmakefirstuc{\MakeTextLowercase{\expandafter\relax\mylong}}\\%
}
\begin{document}\noindent%
\howtodothis{First Letter Should Be Uppercase, All Others Lowercase.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have a look [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7992/command-to-uppercase-the-first-letter-of-each-word-in-a-sentence).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\xmakefirstuc{\MakeTextLowercase{\mylong}}
```

is a shortcut for

```
\expandafter\makefirstuc\expandafter{\MakeTextLowercase{\mylong}}
```

which attempts to expand `\MakeTextLowercase{\mylong}`. Since `\MakeTextLowercase` is robust, no expansion is performed. The TeX primitive `\lowercase` also doesn't expand, so trying to expand to lowercase and then applying `\makefirstuc` won't work. However, it will work if you first expand `\mylong`. Like this:

```
\expandafter\makefirstuc\expandafter{\expandafter\MakeTextLowercase\expandafter{\mylong}}
```

Or using `\xmakefirstuc`:

```
\xmakefirstuc{\expandafter\MakeTextLowercase\expandafter{\mylong}}
```

Here's the MWE:

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}
\newcommand{\howtodothis}[1]{%
    \StrSubstitute{#1}{ }{-}[\mylong]%
    \xmakefirstuc{\expandafter\MakeTextLowercase\expandafter{\mylong}}%
}
\begin{document}\noindent%
\howtodothis{First Letter Should Be Uppercase, All Others Lowercase.}
\end{document}
```

This is the result:

[image: First-letter-should-be-uppercase-all-others-lowercase]

**Edit:** This is actually equivalent to:

```
\MakeTextLowercase{\MakeUppercase{F}irst-Letter-Should-Be-Uppercase,-All-Others-Lowercase.}
```

This may seem a bit contradictory as logic suggests that the `\MakeTextLowercase` should counteract the `\MakeUppercase`, but this is a result of the way that TeX processes tokens (see @egreg's comment below). You can see this from:

```
\lowercase{\uppercase{f}}
```

which produces an uppercase F.

Comment: `\lowercase{\uppercase{f}}` simply passes `\uppercase{f}` to the next stage; the character tokens are transformed using the `\lccode` table and the resulting token list is placed back in the main input stream; then `\uppercase{f}` is processed in a similar way, which produces `F`. If you do `\uppercase{\lowercase{f}}` or `\uppercase{\lowercase{F}}`, you get `f`.

Comment: @egreg I think the point being made in the edit is that people might expect a 'functional' outcome (lowercase-of-uppercase-of-'f'), which as the TeX experts know is not what you get :-)

Comment: @JosephWright There *is* a functional outcome, but in the reverse order.

Comment: @egreg It's contrary to what most computer programmers would expect (as quite often happens with TeX). In most languages `newString = lowercase(uppercase(orgString))` would result in a lowercase string. I'll edit my edit.

Answer (score 4):

Case changing use TeX primitives is not expandable, which is why trying to 'force the issue' isn't easy to get right here. [Nicola has shown how to handle this using `mfirstuc`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/197033). A 'classical' approach to the same issue
is to split the first token off from all of the rest, for example

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{textcase}
\newcommand\howtodothis[1]{%
  \howtodothisaux#1\stop
}
\newcommand\howtodothisaux{}
\long\def\howtodothisaux#1#2\stop{%
  \MakeTextUppercase{#1}%
  \MakeTextLowercase{#2}%
}
\begin{document}\noindent%
\howtodothis{First Letter Should Be Uppercase, All Others Lowercase.}
\end{document}
```

With an up-to-date `expl3`, you can do this using the expandable `\text_titlecase:n` function and no need to split the input:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand{\howtodothis}[1]{%
  \text_titlecase:n {#1}%
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}\noindent%
\howtodothis{First Letter Should Be Uppercase, All Others Lowercase.}
\end{document}
```