# Capitalize editortype field

Tags: biblatex

I want the first letter of the `editortype` field to always be in uppercase in the bibliography.

So I tried this:

**MWE**

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{batman, editor = {Batman}}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\MakeCapital{#1}}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

It prints:

> Batman, ed.

While what I want is:

> Batman, Ed.

---

`biblatex`'s manual describes the `\MakeCapital` command: “Similar to \MakeUppercase but only coverts the first printable character in ⟨text⟩ to uppercase.” So I expected it to work, but it doesn't.

At the same time, changing the `editortype` field format in other ways *does* work… if I do `\emph{#1}` the field is emphasized.

Since `\MakeCapital` doesn't work, I also tried using the command [in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8006), but it still doesn't work and the field gets all messed up. (Maybe I did something wrong.)

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\bibsentence#1}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you modify the `editor` macros anyway you can switch from `\bibstring` which gives context sensitive capitalisation to `\bibcpstring` which capitalises all the time.

For example

```
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{editor+othersstrg}{%
  \iffieldundef{editortype}
    {\ifboolexpr{
       test {\ifnumgreater{\value{editor}}{1}}
       or
       test {\ifandothers{editor}}
     }
       {\def\abx@tempa{editors}}
       {\def\abx@tempa{editor}}}
    {\ifboolexpr{
       test {\ifnumgreater{\value{editor}}{1}}
       or
       test {\ifandothers{editor}}
     }
       {\edef\abx@tempa{\thefield{editortype}s}}
       {\edef\abx@tempa{\thefield{editortype}}}}%
  \let\abx@tempb=\empty
  \ifnamesequal{editor}{translator}
    {\appto\abx@tempa{tr}%
     \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{translator}}}
    {}%
  \ifnamesequal{editor}{commentator}
    {\appto\abx@tempa{co}%
     \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{commentator}}}
    {\ifnamesequal{editor}{annotator}
       {\appto\abx@tempa{an}%
        \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{annotator}}}
       {}}%
  \ifnamesequal{editor}{introduction}
    {\appto\abx@tempa{in}%
     \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{introduction}}}
    {\ifnamesequal{editor}{foreword}
       {\appto\abx@tempa{fo}%
        \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{foreword}}}
       {\ifnamesequal{editor}{afterword}
          {\appto\abx@tempa{af}%
           \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{afterword}}}
          {}}}%
  \ifbibxstring{\abx@tempa}
    {\printtext[editortype]{\bibcpstring{\abx@tempa}}\abx@tempb}
    {\usebibmacro{editorstrg}}}
\makeatother
```

But there are several places at which you would have to change `\bibstring`s to `\bibcpstring`s, so that might lead to quite a lot of code amassing with only minor changes. Of course you can use the [`xpatch` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch) to patch the macros, the example from above then reduces to

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchbibmacro{editor+othersstrg}
  {\bibstring{\abx@tempa}}
  {\bibcpstring{\abx@tempa}}
  {}{\typeout{could not patch editor+othersstrg for uppercase strings}}
\makeatother
```

---

But you can also smuggle a `\bibsentence` into the `editortype` format. I would consider this not the nicest solution, but probably it is the most practical one (being far shorter than the alternative above)

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\bibsentence#1}
```