# Is there a command to make first letter upper case?

Tags: fonts

I found there are many commands in LaTex to satisfy all kinds of requirements of font shape. For example, `\textsc{...}` for `Small Capitals` and  `\uppercase{...}` for `UPPERCASE`, etc. See the following picture, which is form [Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Fonts).
[image: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Fonts]

However, I failed to find a command to make first letter upper case, that is to say, to make `first letter upper case` as `First Letter Upper Case` does it exist?

Comment: I'd say it's an exact duplicate of [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7992/command-to-uppercase-the-first-letter-of-each-word-in-a-sentence), isn't it?

Comment: Please check this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7992/command-to-uppercase-the-first-letter-of-each-word-in-a-sentence

Comment: @ebo All of them? What about `\uppercase`?

Comment: Several of the commands you list are not LaTeX commands at all. They are provided only by certain font support packages. (And isn't `\em` TeX rather than LaTeX, for example?)

Comment: Their picture is clearly wrong in several respects e.g. it suggests oblique and italics are the same shape.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I am not an expert in the LaTx, I don't know there are many errors in this.  As I mentioned in the post, the picture directly obtained  from the Wikibooks: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Fonts. Can you list all the wrong respects such that we can make a correction of the Wikibooks for the purpose of benefitting the readers,

Comment: See the `titlecaps` package

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Yes, using the `mfirstuc` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}
\begin{document}
\capitalisewords{first letter upper case}
\end{document}
```

Moreover, one can exclude some words (as "a", "an", "the", "at", "by", "for", etc.)  to follow  capitalization styles with `\MFUnocap{`*word*`}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}
\MFUnocap{are}
\MFUnocap{or}
\MFUnocap{etc}
\begin{document}
\capitalisewords{first letters are upper case or lower case, etc}.
\end{document}
```

In this case, the result should be:

> First Letters are Upper Case or Lower Case, etc.

However, note that this package use plain spaces to determine what is a word, so if you exclude "case" will work only in the first match, because the second time the word is really "case," (with a comma).

Alternatively, the `titlecaps` package  can perform the same task but with taking care of the punctuation signs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlecaps}
\Addlcwords{are or etc}
\begin{document}
\titlecap{first letters are upper case or lower case, etc.}
\end{document}
```

The output is exactly the same, but note that the final period was inside the capitalized string and  "etc" was correctly not capitalized.

Also note that your mileage may vary with both packages if there are text formatting commands inside the text string, that make the capitalization task much more complex. For example,  both packages manage well `\textit{xxx}`, `\emph{xxx}` fail only with `titlecaps`, `\itshape xxx` fail with only  `mfirstuc`  but `{\itshape xxx}` fail in both packages (although not in the same way).

Comment: It's also possible to exclude words from case-changing with `mfirstuc` (e.g. `\MFUnocap{etc}`). The `mfirstuc-english` package does this for common English words that shouldn't be case-changed, but you can add additional words as required.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot  My apologies for not remember this. I will edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: Do you mean `correctly not capitalized` rather than `not capitalized correctly`? The latter sounds to me like `incorrectly not capitalized` but isn't `etc.` correctly not capitalized?

Comment: +1. But I agree with cfr. I think you mean: '... "etc" was, correctly, not capitalized'. (Note I am off-setting the 'correctly' here only for emphasis: I'd also suggest 'correctly not capitalized'.)

Comment: @cfr  and jon Thanks, It was a typo for lack of sleep. Fixed.

Comment: I'll have to look at the punctuation problem. Incidentally, there's also a difference between the two packages if there's any markup in argument. For example, `first \emph{letters} are upper case or lower case, etc`

Comment: @NicolaTalbot. Thanks, I edited the answer to point also this differences ... and thanks also for your packages.

Comment: if the string to capitalize is in a newcommand, titlecaps works but not mfirstuc, see `\newcommand{\myword}{hello } \titlecap{\myword} \capitalisewords{\myword} `

Comment: I'm trying to use `\capitalisewords{\citet{someref}}` but it's showing up with missing letters and @ signs.

Comment: @AlecJacobson These commands can fail even with a simple command to use italics. What you expected in a complex command that read in a data base? This is only for a short plain text. I suggest you use JabRef to normalize names in the .bib file. Is only 2-3 clicks in the contextual menu in the author field, but note that names  can be printed "as is" in the .bib file, all  in uppercase, or in lowercase, depending on the bibliography style that you are using.

Comment: That doesn't quite solve my use case (which probably deserves its own question if I get around to it): The name is "von Twinkle". In the references or in the middle of a sentence the v should be lowercase. But at the beginning of a sentence my styleguide says it should be capital. So I need `\citet{vonTwinkle}` to be "von Twinkle [2023]" in the middle of a sentence but `\capitalizefirst{\citet{vonTwinkle}}` to be "Von Twinkle [2023]" when I use it at the beginning of a sentence.

Comment: @AlecJacobson Indeed it deserves its own question with a [MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography) but  do not ask about make it work your attempted solution but about any other solution to your actual problem (XY problem),  i.e.,  do not insist on how to make  `\capitalizefirst` work with cites,  but in obtain the right format in the cite with bibtex/biblatex by whatever method.

Answer (score 11):

you can use `\MakeUppercase` command,
when you write `note={\MakeUppercase accessed:2.3.2019}`,
the output: `Accessed 2.3.2019`,
else if you write  `note={\MakeUppercase {accessed}:2.3.2019}`,
the output: `ACCESSED 2.3.2019`,

for example:

```
@misc{ref5, 
title={Use of Images}, url={https://www.hpl.ca/articles/use-images},
note = {\MakeUppercase  Accessed: 25.10.2019}}
```

Comment: The command is `\MakeUppercase`, not `\MakeUpper`...

Comment: I like this solution because it worked immediately, without importing any further package in my document...