# Capitalize first letter of each word when printing list of acronyms

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, capitalization

I use the `glossaries` package and when I print the acronyms using `\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title={List of Abbreviations}]`, part of the output I get is as shown below.

[image]

I have specified acronyms in a separate file as follows:

```
\newacronym{brdf}{BRDF}{bidirectional reflectance distribution function}
\newacronym{cnn}{CNN}{convolutional neural network}
\newacronym{awgn}{AWGN}{additive white Gaussian noise}
```

Is there a way to capitalize first letter of all words in the list of acronyms ONLY, when printing? (And have them in lower-case in the text)

Edit:

**example**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt]{report}
% Abbreviations
\usepackage[acronym,style=super,nogroupskip,nonumberlist,toc]{glossaries}

\loadglsentries{def_abr} % file with acronyms
\makeglossaries

\begin{document} 
% abstract, toc, list of figures here
\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title={List of Abbreviations}]


\chapter*{Example Usage}
 \gls{brdf}, \gls{awgn}, \gls{psnr}, \gls{cnn}
% chapters
\end{document}
```

**def_abr.tex** file:

```
\newacronym{brdf}{BRDF}{bidirectional reflectance distribution function}
\newacronym{cnn}{CNN}{convolutional neural network}
\newacronym{psnr}{PSNR}{peak-signal-to-noise ratio}
\newacronym{snr}{SNR}{signal to noise ratio}
\newacronym{awgn}{AWGN}{additive white Gaussian noise}
```

Comment: Show a complete example that can be used for tests. That makes it much easier to help you.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer added.

Comment: That's not a complete example. It has no \documentclass command, I can't compile it due to the reference to an external file and as it doesn't use the acronyms the list will be empty.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Apologies. Is update ok?

Comment: Acronym `psnr` not defined.

Comment: There is an extra `}` after the CNN definition, otherwise it looks ok I think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an alternative approach that uses [`glossaries-extra`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra) (an extension to the `glossaries` package):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt]{report}
% Abbreviations
\usepackage[acronym,style=super,nogroupskip,nonumberlist]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries
\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}
\loadglsentries{def_abr} % file with acronyms

\glssetcategoryattribute{acronym}{glossdesc}{title}

\begin{document} 
% abstract, toc, list of figures here
\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title={List of Abbreviations}]


\chapter*{Example Usage}
 \gls{brdf}, \gls{awgn}, \gls{psnr}, \gls{cnn}
% chapters
\end{document}
```

(I've omitted the `toc` option as it's the default for `glossaries-extra`).

This produces on page 1:

[image: List of Abbreviations AWGN Additive White Gaussian Noise BRDF Bidirectional Reflectance Distribution Function CNN Convolutional Neural Network PSNR Peak-Signal-To-Noise Ratio]

and page 2:

[image: Example Usage bidirectional reflectance distribution function (BRDF), additive white Gaussian noise (AWGN), peak-signal-to-noise ratio (PSNR), convolutional neural network (CNN)]

The `glossaries` package automatically loads `mfirstuc` (which was originally developed as part of the `glossaries` package). The `title` attribute uses `\capitalisewords` to convert the case. You can control whether or not to capitalise the hyphenated parts of words using `\MFUhyphentrue` and `\MFUhyphenfalse`. The default is the false setting, which is why the above has "Peak-signal-to-noise".

The following switches it on:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt]{report}
% Abbreviations
\usepackage[acronym,style=super,nogroupskip,nonumberlist]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries
\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}
\loadglsentries{def_abr} % file with acronyms

\glssetcategoryattribute{acronym}{glossdesc}{title}
\MFUhyphentrue

\begin{document} 
% abstract, toc, list of figures here
\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title={List of Abbreviations}]


\chapter*{Example Usage}
 \gls{brdf}, \gls{awgn}, \gls{psnr}, \gls{cnn}
% chapters
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: image of list of abbreviations]

To prevent words like "to" from being changed use the `mfirstuc-english` package or set up exceptions with `\MFUnocap` (for example, `\MFUnocap{to}`).

Comment: Elegant solution! However with `\MFUnocap{to}` and `\MFUhyphentrue` exception didn't work for me.

Comment: @Sndn Sorry I should've checked that. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\titlecap` to capitalize the 1st letter of each word in the List of Abbreviations.  You can even exclude words like `to` from being capitalized.  The key is to turn on the meaning of `\titlecap` for the glossary print, and turn it off elsewhere.

I am not a glossaries user, but I am sure there is a way to automate the process so that the `\titlecap` macro need not be added to each entry.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{titlecaps}
\Addlcwords{to}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{glsfile}
\newacronym{brdf}{BRDF}{\titlecap{bidirectional reflectance distribution function}}
\newacronym{cnn}{CNN}{\titlecap{convolutional neural network}}
\newacronym{psnr}{PSNR}{\titlecap{peak-signal-\relax to-noise ratio}}
\newacronym{snr}{SNR}{\titlecap{signal to noise ratio}}
\newacronym{awgn}{AWGN}{\titlecap{additive white Gaussian noise}}
\end{filecontents*}
% Abbreviations
\usepackage[acronym,style=super,nogroupskip,nonumberlist,toc]{glossaries}

\loadglsentries{glsfile} % file with acronyms
\makenoidxglossaries
\begin{document} 
% abstract, toc, list of figures here
\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\printnoidxglossary[type=\acronymtype,title={List of Abbreviations}]
\renewcommand\titlecap[1]{#1}

\chapter*{Example Usage}
 \gls{brdf}, \gls{awgn}, \gls{psnr}, \gls{cnn}, \gls{snr}
% chapters
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to redefine the `\glossentry` command that is used to print the entries in the glossary table. In the MWE below I have used the `\makefirstuc` command from the `mfirstuc` package to make the first letter of the entry upper case. The definitions in the text remain lower case.

The code is not very clean but I could not figure out how to apply the `\makefirstuc` command directly on the `\glossentrydesc` command or on the argument of this command so I opted for a similar construct as in the `mfirstuc` package manual.

Edit: on closer reading the OP asked to capitalize all words. `mfirstuc` has a command for that (`\capitalisewords`), and also has a shortcut for expansion (`\ecapitalisewords`).

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt]{report}
% Abbreviations
\usepackage[acronym,style=super,nogroupskip,nonumberlist,toc]{glossaries}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}

\loadglsentries{def_abr} % file with acronyms
\makeglossaries

\begin{document} 
\gls{brdf}, \gls{awgn}, \gls{psnr}, \gls{cnn}

\renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%  Change the displayed items
\glstarget{#1}{\glossentryname{#1}} %
& \ecapitalisewords{\glossentrydesc{#1}}% Description
\tabularnewline
}

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title={List of Abbreviations}]
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]
Sources:

[glossaries: How to customize list of symbols with additional column for units?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269565/glossaries-how-to-customize-list-of-symbols-with-additional-column-for-units)

[Is there a command to make first letter upper case?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/335990/is-there-a-command-to-make-first-letter-upper-case)

Note that the first question redefines `\glossentry` in the context of a `glossarystyle`, that is probably better if you use multiple types of glossaries (or in general if you prefer cleaner code).