# Capitalize first letter of a defined variable

Tags: capitalization

I'm trying to capitalize the first, and only the first letter of line which I have defined as `\mytext`. I've used `{\MakeUppercase put text here?}`... until now. But now I have it as a variable

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
  \def \mytext {hi how are you?}       

{\MakeUppercase hi how are you?} \par        % => Hi how are you?
{\MakeUppercase \mytext}                     % => HI HOW ARE YOU?
\end{document}
```

How can I make the first letter of the defined variable capitalized?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Command to uppercase the first letter of each word in a sentence](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7992/command-to-uppercase-the-first-letter-of-each-word-in-a-sentence)

Comment: @Moriambar, I had already seen that question and it's answer and I didn't quite get what would answer my question.

Comment: @Moriambar although that question does cover it, its complexified by the addition of the indexing requirement.

Comment: @PaulStanley I understand. Sorry!

Comment: See David's answer, below. Here is what happened: `{\MakeUppercase x}` applies uppercase to whatever x is. If x is `\mytext` it applies uppercase to the text as a unit, then writes it out. But with the `\expandafter` used, `\mytext` is first written out (virtually) THEN uppercase is applied, so it catches just the first letter of the text.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
  \expandafter\MakeUppercase \mytext
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's another approach:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mfirstuc}

\begin{document}
  \def \mytext {hi how are you?}

  \xmakefirstuc{\mytext}
\end{document}
```

This works much like David's answer, but can also handle awkward cases where the text includes text-block formatting commands (where the first argument is the text that needs formatting). For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mfirstuc}

\begin{document}
  \def \mytext {hi how are you?}

  \xmakefirstuc{\mytext}

  \def \mytext {\emph{hi} how are you?}

  \xmakefirstuc{\mytext}
\end{document}
```

[image: Hi how are you? *Hi* how are you?]

In the second case above, it's effectively doing:

```
\emph{\MakeUppercase hi} how are you?
```

A simple `\expandafter\MakeUppercase\mytext` approach causes:

```
\MakeUppercase\emph{hi} how are you?
```

which doesn't work as it's attempting `\MakeUppercase{\emph}`.

The commands provided by `mfirstuc` don't work with declarations (such as `\em` or `\itshape`) as the package is designed for semantic markup not free-form formatting. You can use semantic markup to deal with quoted or parenthetical material. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mfirstuc}

\begin{document}

  \newcommand*{\qt}[1]{``#1''}

  \def \mytext {\qt{hi how are you?}}

  \xmakefirstuc{\mytext}
\end{document}
```

[image: “Hi how are you?”]

Another point to consider is whether or not you intend using UTF-8 characters with `inputenc`. This isn't a problem with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, but with LaTeX the UTF-8 character is treated as two octets. For example:

```
\def \mytext {ĥi how are you?}
\expandafter\MakeUppercase\mytext
```

This causes the error:

```
! Argument of \UTFviii@two@octets has an extra }.
```

because `\MakeUppercase` has only grabbed the first octet. The same error occurs with `\xmakefirstuc` unless you load `datatool-base` (at least v2.24) after `inputenc` and before `mfirstuc`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{datatool-base}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}

\begin{document}

  \def \mytext {ĥi how are you?}

  \xmakefirstuc{\mytext}
\end{document}
```

[image: Ĥi how are you?]

Comment: Is there a way to protect a certain word and keep it unchanged? For example, suppose you want to write the sentence: "Welcome to the USA", whether it is written in all caps (WELCOME TO THE USA) or not (welcome to the USA).  I thought about using ```\makefirstuc{\MakeLowercase{ \mytext }}``` but it does not do the job. Any tip? It would be nice if using braces around the word, it could preserve as it is, for example using ```welcome to the {USA}``` .