# Expanding to separate letters or capitalizing first letter of macro result

Tags: expansion, capitalization

The following code produces `Die Patientin ist nicht die Patientin.` I'd like to have the second `die` also capitalized.

Using `\edef` for `\p@tcnom` the whole argument is capitalized instead of only the first letter.

This is different from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/362129/capitalize-first-letter-of-a-defined-variable) since `\p@tctst` already solves that issue. So it's similar, but another level of indirection. ;)

Could some TeX wizard please shine a light on this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\ucletter{\expandafter\makeupcase}
\def\makeupcase#1{\uppercase{#1}}
\newif\ifmale

\makeatletter
\def\p@tctst{die Patientin}
\def\p@tcnom{\ifmale{der Patient}\else{die Patientin}\fi}
\def\mytesti#1{\ucletter\p@tctst}
\def\pattest#1{\ucletter\p@tcnom}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\mytesti{void} ist nicht \pattest{void}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use `\def\p@tcnom{\ifmale der Patient\else die Patientin\fi}` (without braces inside the definition) and `\def\pattest#1{\expandafter\ucletter\p@tcnom}` (instead of `\edef` in the first definition).

Comment: @SergeiGolovan Perhaps convert your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add `\tracingmacros=1` just before the use of `\pattest` you'll see in the log file what actually happens. Mine shows the following:

```
\pattest #1->\ucletter \p@tcnom 
#1<-void

\ucletter ->\expandafter \makeupcase 

\p@tcnom ->\ifmale der Patient\else die Patientin\fi 

\makeupcase #1->\uppercase {#1}
#1<-\ifmale 

...
```

This means that `\makeupcase` is applied to the `\ifmale` token and not to the expanded string. So another expansion is necessary, for which `\expandafter` before `\ucletter` would help.

Another issue is with the braces. When you replace the `\pattest` definition by `\def\pattest#1{\expandafter\ucletter\p@tcnom}` you'll get the following (againg in the log):

```
\pattest #1->\expandafter \ucletter \p@tcnom 
#1<-void

\p@tcnom ->\ifmale {der Patient}\else {die Patientin}\fi 

\ucletter ->\expandafter \makeupcase 

\makeupcase #1->\uppercase {#1}
#1<-die Patientin

...
```

So the braces group the letters and make the whole word an argument to `\makeupcase`. That's why all the letters switch case. You'll have to remove the braces.

Also, I don't really understand why do you define `\pattest` with an argument which is thrown away then, but it's irrelevant for the problem here.

The following code is a minimal modification of your MWE which produces the correct output with only the first letter is uppercased:

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\ucletter{\expandafter\makeupcase}
\def\makeupcase#1{\uppercase{#1}}
\newif\ifmale

\makeatletter
\def\p@tctst{die Patientin}
\def\p@tcnom{\ifmale der Patient\else die Patientin\fi}
\def\mytesti#1{\ucletter\p@tctst}
\def\pattest#1{\expandafter\ucletter\p@tcnom}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\mytesti{void} ist nicht \pattest{void}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: The empty arguments come from the encompassing structure. I had a hard time tracking down what happened there and finally found a working construction. Thanks for the \tracingmacros hint.