# How to capitalize the first letter of a glossary or acronym description

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, capitalization, uppercase

I'm using the glossaries package to define acronyms but in one place I want to start a sentence with the full text of the acronym:

```
\subsection{Randomly-occurring deterministic disturbances}

\acrlong{RODD} (\acrshort{RODD}) are a family of ...
```

[image]

However, because `\acrlong{RODD}` is at the start of the sentence the first letter needs be capitalized.

Preliminary tests of two options I tried:

```
\MakeUppercase abc def ghi  % works: Abc def ghi
\makefirstuc{abc def ghi}  % works: Abc def ghi
```

Attempts to apply these to the glossary item:

```
\MakeUppercase \acrlong{RODD}
```

This raises the following errors:

```
Incomplete \ifx; all text was ignored after line 17. \include{chapitre2}
Missing \endcsname inserted. \include{chapitre3}
Incomplete \ifcsname; all text was ignored after line 287.
```

```
\MakeUppercase{\acrlong{RODD}}
```

No errors, but the description is not capitalized

```
\makefirstuc{\acrlong{RODD}}
```

Raises the following errors:

```
Missing \endcsname inserted. \makefirstuc{\acrlong{RODD}}
Package glossaries Error: Glossary entry `\MakeTextUppercase {R}ODD' has not been defined. \makefirstuc{\acrlong{RODD}}
```

Using the method described [here](https://latexref.xyz/Upper-and-lower-case.html):

```
\expandafter\MakeUppercase\expandafter{\acrlong{RODD}}
```

Raises the following errors:

```
Undefined control sequence. \expandafter\MakeUppercase \acrlong
Undefined control sequence. \expandafter\MakeUppercase \acrlong
Undefined control sequence. \expandafter\MakeUppercase \acrlong
...
```

Using the method described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/362130/179342)

```
\expandafter\MakeUppercase \acrlong{RODD}
```

Raises the following errors:

```
Undefined control sequence. \expandafter\MakeUppercase \acrlong
Undefined control sequence. \expandafter\MakeUppercase \acrlong
Undefined control sequence. \expandafter\MakeUppercase \acrlong
...
```

FYI: what I am trying to do is the opposite of what this person wanted where they wanted the descriptions capitalized in the acronym list but lower case in the document:
[Capitalize the first letter in acronym list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57975/179342)

Answer (score 1):

`glossaries` already offers sentence case commands for most of its referencing macros. In your case, you are looking for `\Acrlong`.

Comment: Oh right, that's great! Should have occurred to me to check that.