# Is there a way to automatically make each letter of the first word capitalized in the section title?

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, titlesec, section-titles

Was wondering if there was a way to redefine \section{this is an example} so that the section title shown in the pdf is actually "This is a Section Title". I know package sectsty has an option to \maketitlecase for the sections but I was wondering whether there was a way to do this automatically without using \maketitlecase after every \section{} instance?

This same section title should also not mess up the TOC.

Comment: Kind of related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7992/56823

Comment: You can load  `titlesec`  and `\titlecaps`, and use `\titleformat*{\section}{\titlecap}` in the preamble.

Comment: @Bernard - I tried titlesecs but it looks like its messing up the hyperlinks

Comment: @AustinBenny: Could you post a small, yet complete; code illustrating this problem?